# IBM Mobile First Push Notification not working for Hybrid application

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm having an issue receiving push notifications on android devices

Steps I followed:

1. Created an app with all security configuration
2. Created an adapter for submitting notification
3. Built and deployed the application and adapter
4. Opened the app in my device (android) and subscribed for the Push Notification

   a. Used form authentication (using j_security_check)

   b. Provided a mobile number as username
5. Invoked the adapter's submit notification function.

   a. Got response saying the Push Notification is sent to the user

But no Push Notification appearing on device (android). Tried on couple of devices (android), but having same issue.

How can I debug the issue or what am I doing wrong here.

P.S I have the sample Push application working fine. But on integration with my application it's not working. Only the difference is the login page

Sample Push App login page

```html
<form id="loginForm" >
  <input type="text" id="usernameInputField" placeholder="Username"/><br />
  <input type="password" id="passwordInputField" placeholder="Password"/><br/>      
  <input type="button" id="loginButton" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Button Bind Code

```
$('#loginButton').bind('click', function () {
  var reqURL = '/j_security_check';
  var options = {};
  options.parameters = {
    j_username : $('#usernameInputField').val(),
    j_password : $('#passwordInputField').val()
  };
  options.headers = {};

  pushAppRealmChallengeHandler.submitLoginForm(reqURL, options, pushAppRealmChallengeHandler.submitLoginFormCallback);
});
```

My App login page

```
<span class="fields">
  <input type="text" data-role="none" placeholder="Mobile Number" class="input_text" id="mobnum"/>
  <input type="text" data-role="none" placeholder="Name" class="input_text" id="name"/>
  <input type="text" data-role="none" placeholder="Email ID" class="input_text" id="email"/>
  <input type="text" data-role="none" placeholder="Organization" class="input_text" id="org"/>
  <span class="next_button"><a href="#" data-role="none" id="nxt_btn2"></a></span>
</span>
```

Button Bind Code

```
$('#nxt_btn2').bind('click', function () {
  var reqURL = '/j_security_check';
  var options = {};
  options.parameters = {
    j_username : $('#mobnum').val(),
    j_password : $('#email').val()
  };

  options.headers = {};

  pushAppRealmChallengeHandler.submitLoginForm(reqURL, options, pushAppRealmChallengeHandler.submitLoginFormCallback);

});
```

Comment: @IdanAdar I have added the code. Please have a look

Comment: Add to your question the following missing information: Full MobileFirst version and build number; LogCat log from the time the push is sent and it not being received by the device. Your error indicates an issue related to setup and not to code.

Comment: @Ranju have you added pushsender tag in appliationdescriptor.xml file which helps your device to register your device in GCM and in your steps you havent mentioned about creating and getting Sender id and key in the GCM,

Comment: @IdanAdar  MobileFirst version is 6.3.0.00 - 201502014-1702. Will check and get you the logs.

Comment: @KawineshSK Pushsender exists.  <android securityTest="PushApplication-strong-mobile-securityTest" version="1.0">
 <worklightSettings include="false"/>
 <pushSender key="xxxxx" senderId="xxxxxxxx"/>
 <security>
  <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
  <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
  <publicSigningKey/>
  <packageName/>
 </security>
</android>

Comment: @Ranju have you created your pushsender key by giving permissions in the API & auth  tab of your project in the Google Developer Console. you have to  enable  API's. Goggle Cloud Messaging.

Comment: @KawineshSK I had actually forgot to enable the api. Enabled it today morning.. Thanks for pointing out. But still am not getting Notifications. So what you would suggest now I have to do. 1. Create new event source and adapter. 2. Regenerate API keys

Comment: @KawineshSK Regenerating the API keys worked for me. Thanks a lot Kawinesh and Idan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Cloud Messaging for Android was not enabled. So I was getting subscribed and messages were being sent form MobileFirst server to GCM but since the API was not enabled in GCM I was not getting the notfications on my device.

Steps Taken

1. Enabled Cloud Messaging for Android API in GCM
2. Regenerated the API Key.

Special thanks to @kawineshSK and IdanAdar